# How to center text vertically if line break occurs

Tags: html, css, center

Basically the question I have is about text inside a container. When the screen size gets smaller, it breaks into the next line. At that point, it is no longer centered vertically, because a new line appeared.

How can I keep it vertically centered?

```html
<div class="low">
  <h4 class="title"> Text to be centered. </h4>
</div>
```

I usually adjust padding for every line break, but that is cumbersome and time consuming. There is got to be a better way.

Comment: Try making your line-height of the h4 and the div both 100%

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `display: flex;` to make it vertically centered:

```
.low {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `text-align` property to `center`. However if the width of the container is such that it's contents cannot be centrally aligned it will fail.

```css
.low {
    width: 50px;
}

.title {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="low">
     <h4 class="title"> Text to be centered. </h4>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4oacwqcp/

Comment: ...you did not read the question properly. It's about vertically aligning

Comment: @PennyLiu please don't make superfluous edits like changing indentation spacing amounts, and definitely please don't remove links to JSFiddle from answers.

Comment: @TylerH I understand. No unnecessary spacing changes, and I'll keep JSFiddle links in responses.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
div {
    display: table;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 50px;
}

h4 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="low">
    <h4 class="title"> Text to be centered. </h4>
</div>
```